# conjunction - how meaning "however"

Tags: conjunctions

Does the following use of "how" sound OK?

> We must cut costs **how** we can.
>
> I will decorate the room **how** I want.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I will decorate the room however I want to (either repeat the main verb or just leave to). **However** is more formal and stronger, too.

Comment: While not sounding quite natural (in particular the first sentence), I will note that they are still completely understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

> We must cut costs in ways we can.
>
> We must cut costs how we can.
>
> We must cut costs in whatever way we can.
>
> We must cut costs however we can.

**ever** expands the ambit of the cost-cutting measures to include *all* possible ways.  The versions without **ever** do not exclude anything; **ever** simply makes explicit the notion that *every* option is on the table for consideration.